# Playwright - "Verify it's you" message only for chromium, while trying to login to Google

Tags: puppeteer, integration-testing, chromium, auth0, playwright

I'm writing a Playwright test that starts with a Google Auth0 login. After I fill my test user and password in the UI (google login), in Firefox and Webkit the authentication passes successfully, while, on Chromium, I'm getting the `Verify it's you` message (with a "send sms" message).

- The account does not have 2 steps authentication.
- When it happened locally, I opened the browser in headful mode, and after few clicks (which I assume "told" the browser that I'm a real user) the problem disappeared (I can now run my tests in headless mode locally). But, it still happens on CI (GitHub)
- I run the test with chromium flags: `--disable-dev-shm-usage` and `--disable-web-security`.

I couldn't find any data about it anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

When Google determines that a user is logging in from an unknown device or a new location, they may prompt the user with an additional login challenge.

The login challenge that the user receives depends on the information that associated with the account.

Does the prompt say "Enter a phone number to get a text message" or something else like "This device isn't recognized..."

If the former I believe you can circumvent this extra prompt by having a phone number linked to the Google account in question. If the latter I believe the prompt is once per user per device.

My understanding it is basically Google trying to get a valid phone number for the account (to prevent spam etc).

-- Edit

The only other thing I can think of is that you can temporarily turn off the verify-it's-you challenge, for 10 mins, but only if the account is a member of a Google Workspace or Cloud Identity service. I am not sure this is possible for an unmanaged account - or how useful it would be. The other issue is that for "free services" Google doesn't really offer any kind of support.

Anyhow, you might try "Temporarily turn off login challenges for a user" -
https://support.google.com/a/answer/12077697

There is also so good information on this verify-it's-you challenge here.

https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2018/04/more-secure-sign-in-chrome.html

It has some notes on disabling the challenge per organization via response headers, but again this is for an organization and managed accounts.

> If you wish to disable the new screen for your organization, you can
> use the X-GoogApps-AllowedDomains HTTP header to identify specific
> domains whose users can access Google services. Users in those domains
> won’t see this additional screen, as we assume those accounts are
> trusted by your users. This header can be set in Chrome via the
> AllowedDomainsForApps group policy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I keep getting the "Verify it's you" message, with a place to add a phone number. I added the phone number and now I have the same message, just with an option to choose a 2FA option (mail/sms etc.). 2FA is disabled + the test is green in FF and Webkit.

Comment: @YanivEfraim - hmm that's annoying. The only other thing I can think of is for managed accounts - see my edit.